# Why do I need to import Entities separately instead of just the Module in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I have a **NestJS application** consisting of modules, each with its own services, controllers, and entities.

Why do I need to import all the required entities directly from various modules into other modules, rather than just importing the corresponding module? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a feature of NestJS that I don't fully understand?

Let's say, I have a **MetaData-module** consisting of:

- MetaDataModule
- MetaDataEntity
- MetaDataService

and an **Image-Module** that shall import the *MetaData-Module* with its entities and service:

- ImageService
- ImageModule
- ImageController

### Showing some code:

**metadata.module.ts:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MetaDataEntity])],
  providers: [MetadataService],
  controllers: [MetadataController],
  exports: [MetadataService],
})
export class MetadataModule {}
```

**metadata.entity.ts:**

```
@Entity({ name: 'metadata' })
@Unique('idx_unique_uuid', ['uuid'])
export class MetaDataEntity extends ImmutableBaseEntity {
  @Column({ name: 'uuid', type: 'varchar', length: 64 })
  @IsUUID()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  uuid: string;

  /// many others properties as well
}
```

**metadata.service.ts:**

```
export class MetadataService {
  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    @InjectRepository(MetaDataEntity) private readonly repository: Repository<MetaDataEntity>,
  ) {}

  // functions...

}
```

**image.module.ts:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [MetadataModule, HttpModule],
  providers: [ImagesService],
  controllers: [ImagesController],
})
export class ImagesModule {}
```

**image.service.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ImagesService {
  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    @InjectRepository(MetaDataEntity) private readonly repository: Repository<MetaDataEntity>,
  ) {}
```

This can't get compiled thanks to the following error:

> ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the
> ImagesService (ConfigService, HttpService, ?). Please make sure that
> the argument MetaDataEntityRepository at index [2] is available in the
> ImagesModule context.

In order to fix this issue, I had to import the MetaData-Entity into the Image-Module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MetaDataEntity]), HttpModule],
  providers: [ImagesService, TypeOrmModule],
  controllers: [ImagesController],
})
export class ImagesModule {}
```

The issue is, that on all other Modules where I want to import MetaDataEntity, I have to import it with `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MetaDataEntity]`.
Even in other Modules, that are importing the ImageModule, I need to import the MetaDataEntity separately.

At this point, I'm curious what the purpose of a Module is in NestJS. According to the official docs at https://docs.nestjs.com/modules I understood it like importing a Module should provide all parts of the module for the importing module. But that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

This is how providers in NestJS work. What `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Entity])` is doing under the hood is creating an injection token for `"EntityRepository"` in the context of the current module. It'd be just like making your own custom provider:

```js
{
  provide: "EntityRepository",
  inject: [getConnectionToken()],
  useFactory: (connection: TypeOrmConnection) => connection.getRepository(Entity)
}
```

To expose this provider to other modules *from* this module, you would normally need to add the injection token to the module's `exports` array. However, when you have a module like this, you might not know what the injection token is, so what you can do instead is make use of something called [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting). In this case, you have `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` in the `imports` array, and add `TypeOrmModule` to the `exports` array. This will expose the `"EntityRepository"` token to other modules that import this module, and make things work the way you want to.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exporting TypeOrmModule was the final solution. Makes code so much more readable :)